# Property values reset OnPost in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, model-binding

I am trying to keep the values of my property for my OnPost method. I set the values in the OnGet method, when I change from the last page to the current. Here's the HTML for the button that redirects to the page with my property:

```
<a class="btn" type="button" asp-page="CreateDate" asp-route-dateString="@Model.model.StartDate.AddDays(i).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
```

Here's the OnGet method:

```
        [BindProperty]
    public DateTime eventDate { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(string dateString)
    {
        var stringToDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        eventDate = stringToDate;
    }
```

Here's the OnPost:

```
        public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        Date date = new Date();
        date.Date1 = eventDate;
        date.Title = Request.Form["Title"];
        date.Description = Request.Form["Description"];

        dateService.AddDate(date, userID);

        return RedirectToPage("Calendar");
    }
```

And lastly the HTML for the OnPost method:

```
<div>
<h5 class="pageTitle">Udfyld formular for at oprette et event for denne dato: @Model.eventDate.ToString("D")</h5>
<form method="post">
    Navn på event:
    <br />
    <input name="Title" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" required autofocus />
    <br />
    Beskrivelse:
    <br />
    <input name="Description" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" required autofocus />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Opret Event" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

I am still very new, so I'm just (hopefully) looking for a simple answer. Thanks!

Comment: `I am trying to keep the values of my property for my OnPost method. `What does this mean?Keep the property in the PageModel which contains the OnPost method?Or redirect page to `Calendar` with the property in OnPost method?

Comment: what you need to read about is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0 - In your case, looks like `hidden fields` best suit your requirement. But for a safer solution, you can look at the other ways.

Answer (score 1):

As you redirect to Calendar page in your OnPost method,you will go to the Calendar page,so you can pass property to the Calendar page and keep property in Calendar PageModel.

OnPost method:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        Date date = new Date();
        date.Date1 = eventDate;
        date.Title = Request.Form["Title"];
        date.Description = Request.Form["Description"];

        dateService.AddDate(date, userID);

        return RedirectToPage("Calendar",date);
    }
```

Calendar.cshtml.cs:

```
public class CalendarModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Date date { get; set; }
        public void OnGet(Date Date)
        {
            date = Date;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is correct and should be marked as the answer.